# Windows 10 Login Screen is Blank - But Remote Desktop is Working

Tags: windows, windows-10, login, login-screen, blank-screen

I am sitting next to my Windows 10 desktop running a remote login session from another computer. If I turn to the desktop that I'm remotely logged into and try to log in directly (requires CTRL-ALT-DEL), the screen remains blank (like it would if it were in power save mode, for example).

There are times when I can login directly without this problem, but I have not determined any cause, one way or the other, for this blank screen behavior.

So the computer is running, as I can use it from a remote desktop application, but it refuses to allow me to login directly or even see anything on the screen.

Things I've tried that have no effect:

- directly logging in after logging out from the remote login
- directly logging in while still logged in remotely
- cycling the power to the monitors of the desktop computer
- rebooting the computer - the problem returns later, so it's not a one-off event
- pressing random keys on the desktop's keyboard
  UPDATED:
- changing monitors, changing keyboard had no effect

This problem differs from the others described on Super User, such as

- [Windows 10 black screen after local login and previous remote desktop session](https://superuser.com/questions/1026423/windows-10-black-screen-after-local-login-and-previous-remote-desktop-session) - this is about a problem after login
- [Windows 7 remote desktop hangs after a successful login](https://superuser.com/questions/637724/windows-7-remote-desktop-hangs-after-a-successful-login) - this is about a problem after login

I have not seen any other questions that address a problem like this one.

Comment: First plan of attack (as it seems to me here) is to try a different monitor. Since Remote Desktop works, I do not think it is the GPU. It could be the connection at the case, but monitor seems more likely.

Comment: Thanks. I have two monitors on the computer, and neither one is functioning (most of the time). I swapped in another monitor and also another keyboard. No luck :(

Comment: If that is true, then you appear to have an intermittent motherboard problem in the area not needed by Remote Desktop Connection.

Answer (score 0):

Several thoughts:

Like John says, it could be the monitor, but to me it sounds like the cables might be off a bit, especially if the problem is intermittent.  Check the monitor and keyboard connections.

Try unplugging and reattaching the usb keyboard on the host machine.

See if changing the keyboard options under resources on the RDP options menu helps as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your testing with additional monitor and keyboard and the fact that the unit works with Remote Desktop Connection, then that points to an intermittent hardware problem on the motherboard in an area not used by RDC (circuitry between GPU and monitor). It is possibly an intermittent fault with the GPU.